# output on a new line in python curses

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I am using curses module in python to display output in real time by reading a file.
The string messages are output to the console using addstr() function
but I am not able to achieve printing to a newline wherever I need.

sample code:

```
import json
import curses
w=curses.initscr()

try:
    while True:
        with open('/tmp/install-report.json') as json_data:
            beta = json.load(json_data)
            w.erase()
            w.addstr("\nStatus Report for Install process\n=========\n\n")
            for a1, b1 in beta.iteritems():
                w.addstr("{0} : {1}\n".format(a1, b1))
            w.refresh()
finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

The above is not really outputting the strings to a new line (notice the \n in addstr()) with each iteration. On the contrary, the script fails off with error if I resize the terminal window.

```
w.addstr("{0} ==> {1}\n".format(a1, b1))
_curses.error: addstr() returned ERR
```

Comment: Why not just `print()` your information? Do you have a reason to need to say, scroll back or interrupt the printing process?

Comment: @WayneWerner well i am trying to output the data in real time as and when a json file gets updated in the backend. and for that i am using curses. something like linux 'top' command format. print() statement wont fit properly in the curses context as i am looping in to read a file constantly. so print() will clutter the console

Comment: @SurestTexas if someone hasn't given a reason they're using a thing I don't presume they have a good reason for it. Experience has shown that most of the time... they don't!

Comment: @SurestTexas have you met software developers? I mean, some people use emacs for crying out loud ;) In all seriousness - aside from saying that they're using curses, is there anything in this question that suggests the need for it? From what I see it's exactly the opposite - the OP is printing out a status report for an install. It's exactly equivalent to seeing an OP post that they're reading a .csv file with pandas and summing one of the columns. Yeah, they *can*, but it's possibly excessive and the OP may not be aware that they could do it another way. Some of us just get enamored by shiny

Comment: "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess" - if it looks like a duck (print statement) and quacks like a duck (print statement) then I'm going to ask if they shouldn't be using a duck (print statement) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not enough program to offer more than general advice:

- you will get an error when printing to the end of the screen if your script does not enable scrolling (see [`window.scroll`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.scroll)).
- if you resize the terminal window, you will have to read the keyboard to dispose of any `KEY_RESIZE` (and ignore errors).

Regarding the expanded question, these features would be used something like this:

```
import json
import curses
w=curses.initscr()
w.scrollok(1) # enable scrolling
w.timeout(1)  # make 1-millisecond timeouts on `getch`

try:
    while True:
        with open('/tmp/install-report.json') as json_data:
            beta = json.load(json_data)
            w.erase()
            w.addstr("\nStatus Report for Install process\n=========\n\n")
            for a1, b1 in beta.iteritems():
                w.addstr("{0} : {1}\n".format(a1, b1))
            ignore = w.getch()  # wait at most 1msec, then ignore it
finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

Comment: i have added additional code in context (edited my original post). i went through the curses documentation but not getting how to implement window.scroll or KEY_RESIZE in my code context

Comment: It works now. one small glitch i see. when the output is more than screen full. i cannot scroll up to see the initial lines of the output. is there a way to scroll up and see the initial output lines .

Comment: That's expected (if your application needs to do this, it has to either use a large-enough **pad** instead of just a window, or use some other way to save the data).